# Finding the center of a low resolution circle/crown in an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I need to find the coordinates of the center of a circle like object, a crown, in an image with typically the resolution 11 X 11. The problem is the circle is not always entirely present in the image and there can be artifacts of pieces from other circles which need to be ignored.
[Circle example without artifacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uw0bp.png)

[Circle example with artifacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXjiF.png)

[Misaligned circle example with artifacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAFgX.png)

Getting the coordinates of the bigger circle is good enough. Edge cases where an artifact gets to be the bigger circle are extreme cases that can be ignored.

I first tried doing the similiarity with imgreg_dft and a circle centred on the middle of the image I generated. But the results are very unpredictable.

Then I tried using scikits props but I think the resolution is too low https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_regionprops.html

for
[Scikit example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VyTP.png)
I get

|  | centroid-0 (y) | centroid-1 (x) | area |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3.121212 | 4.484848 | 33.0 |
| 1 | 0.000000 | 6.500000 | 2.0 |
| 2 | 7.000000 | 2.200000 | 10.0 |

Where what I want is the prop 2 with coordinates (7,2). Though I can't tell it apart from the others automatically. The prop with bigger area is not inside a crown. How could I tell a prop is inside one even if part of the crown can be outside the image?
Another example:
[Scikit example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKIxw.png)

|  | centroid-0 (y) | centroid-1 (x) | area |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3.500000 | 4.366667 | 30.0 |
| 1 | 0.333333 | 6.500000 | 6.0 |
| 2 | 7.166667 | 1.833333 | 6.0 |

Code example:

```
from skimage.measure import label, regionprops,regionprops_table
from skimage.morphology import reconstruction
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

stamp=[[1.         1.         1.         1.         0.         0.4
  1.         0.5        0.        ]
 [1.         1.         1.         1.         0.75       0.5
   0.33333333 0.4        0.83333333]
  [1.         1.         1.         1.         1.         1.
   1.         1.         1.        ]
  [0.57142857 0.         0.         0.         1.         1.
   1.         1.         1.        ]
  [0.         0.2        0.16666667 0.         0.         0.2
   1.         1.         0.2       ]
  [0.75       1.         1.         1.         0.         0.
   1.         0.66666667 0.        ]
  [1.         1.         1.         1.         0.16666667 0.
  1.         0.71428571 0.        ]
  [1.         1.         1.         1.         0.         0.
   1.         1.         0.        ]
  [0.33333333 1.         0.8        0.33333333 0.         0.5
   1.         1.         0.66666667]]

stamp_img=np.array(stamp)
px.imshow(stamp_img, origin="lower")

round_img=np.round(stamp_img)
px.imshow(rec_img, origin="lower")

label_img=label(stamp_img) 
regions=regionprops(label_img)
props = pd.DataFrame(regionprops_table(label_img, properties= 
     ('centroid', 'area',)))
 props
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.